# Create Chart.js pie chart data from PHP

Tags: javascript, php, chart.js

I am working with chart.js and I am trying to get data from PHP but I'm having an issue.

I have the following code:

```
$dataArray = $this->getBlankSupportArray("New");
            $dataArray = $this->getBlankSupportArray("In Progress");
            $dataArray = $this->getBlankSupportArray("Neutralised Parked");
            $dataArray = $this->getBlankSupportArray("Neutralised Pending Shout");
            $dataArray = $this->getBlankSupportArray("Neutralised Pending Shout");
            $dataArray = $this->getBlankSupportArray("Ready To Close");
```

The getBlankSupportArray loos like the following:

```
private function getBlankSupportArray($issueStatus)
        {
            $array[$issueStatus]["value"] = 0;
            $array[$issueStatus]["color"] = "#ffffff";
            $array[$issueStatus]["highlight"] = "#ffffff";
            $array[$issueStatus]["label"] = $issueStatus;
            return $array;
        }
```

Below is the data I am looping round from a mysql result and adding to the array

```
while ($myrow = $result->fetch_array())
                {
                    $issueStatus = $myrow["IssueStatus"];
                    $supportOverview[$issueStatus]["value"] = $myrow["COUNT(*)"];
                    $supportOverview[$issueStatus]["color"] = "#F7464A";
                    $supportOverview[$issueStatus]["highlight"] = "#FF5A5E";
                    $supportOverview[$issueStatus]["label"] = $issueStatus;
                }
```

I am then json_encoding this array.

I think the json_encoding is returning the data in a format not suitable chart.js to process.

The documentation for chart.js says that the data object should be in the following format

```
var data = [
    {
        value: 300,
        color:"#F7464A",
        highlight: "#FF5A5E",
        label: "Red"
    },
    {
        value: 50,
        color: "#46BFBD",
        highlight: "#5AD3D1",
        label: "Green"
    },
    {
        value: 100,
        color: "#FDB45C",
        highlight: "#FFC870",
        label: "Yellow"
    }
]
```

So my question is, how do I get PHP to generate an object that can be sent back to javascript and decoded to be passed into chart.js.

Thans for any help you can provide.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to convert the values in the JSON to numbers, JSON encodes them as strings.

```
parseInt()
```

in Javascript should do the trick.

I got confused with this as well, kept me occupied for weeks.

For PHP Var

```
var pie = [{ value: parseInt(<?PHP VARIABLE?>), color: "#F7464A" }]
```

Comment: So does that mean I need to create an object separately and loop around the json to create the array myself. I was hoping PHP could send the response and I could just put this response straight into chart.js without needing to manually parse the json

Comment: Edited answer for possible PHP.  I am not sure about PHP as I used javascript to get my JSON file and had it as a javascript object. I assume this would work as the PHP would be done before the page is loaded.

Comment: Sorry, don't think I've explained myself, its PHP generating the array and then echoing the json_encoded array which javascript gets as the result of an jquery post

Comment: Nah thats my mistake I get it now, I think you are going to have to parse it in javascript unfortunately. It seems stupid but it had me confused for weeks. Unless there is some way of your ensuring that the array returns a number and not a string of a number

Comment: http://www.lornajane.net/posts/2011/php-returning-numeric-values-in-json

You could use the JSON NUMERIC CHECK in this article

Comment: Thanks for your help, I've parsed the json as you suggested and used the parseint on the value and it looks like its working now. It is confusing, especially as the bar chart you can just drop a json object straight into it and it wors

Answer (score 0):

Hi I was facing the same problem and i found solution. which is working absolutly fine.

My json data 
`[{"week_name":"18","taskcount":"4"},{"week_name":"16","taskcount":"17"},{"week_name":"15","taskcount":"11"},{"week_name":"13","taskcount":"20"}]`
so,

```
$obj = json_decode($jsonData);

var PieData = [<?php for($i=0;$i<count($obj);$i++){ ?>
{

    value: <?php echo $obj[$i]->taskcount;?>,

    label: 'Week '+<?php echo $obj[$i]->week_name;?>

  },
          <?php } ?>
];
```

Answer (score 0):

For all those still wondering how to pass an integer PHP variable as a value in Chartjs javascript here's how:

```
var PieData        = [
      {
        value    : parseInt(<?php echo $variable; ?>),
        color    : '#00c0ef',
        highlight: '#00c0ef',
        label    : 'Blue'
      },
```

I used this with Adminlte 3 - Hope it helps!